# How To Enable Android LED Notification Light Even When The Screen Is Unlocked

Tags: android

I am developing an Android alarm app in which I enable the notification LED when the alarm is going off. I have found that it only comes on when the screen back-light is off. Is it possible to enable the notification LED all the time what ever state the screen is in. I then disable it when the alarm is stopped.

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible on Android.

Comment: Hi There, I though so. The only reason I asked was because I have and app that does this.

Comment: This should not be possible. The app is most likely using root or exploiting a bug that I am not aware of.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up.